# Pagination on custom post type not working - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

I am having some trouble with pagination on my custom post types. I am using plugin called `Wp-PageNavi`.

I am calling it in template with function :

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );
```

and my query looks like that / mo-sales is my custom post type

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
$args = array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_type' => 'mo-sales',
            'posts_per_page' => 2
     );

     $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Basically this is what i am using on my blog page and there is working perfectly, but on the custom post type it is not, and i am not sure why. When i click on page 2/3/4 returns 404page
Here is link for that page -> http://modatadev.wpengine.com/mo-sales/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-setting your Permalinks?

Settings → Permalinks > Save Changes

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen